# Confusion in Pandas User's Guide

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am bit lost in Pandas User's Guide's Chapter Essential Basic Functionality:https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html

In the link above, I am trying to follow/learn the Section "Applying elementwise functions". My confusion is that the example here shows that the value 1.394981 has a length of 18 (instead of 8). On what basis? I know the len and str functions well and when I ran the same same thing on console, I got the answer that I expect:

```
>>> print(len(str(1.394981)))
8
```

Comment: a lot of REPLs (like notebooks and consoles, and this case the documentation) don't display the full precision of floating point decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the guide, when that number is created, the function [`np.random.rand`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) is used. If you try printing a number created by this function, you'll see its exact precision:

```
n = np.random.rand(1)[0]
print(n)
#0.07423561514653387
```

But, if you use it inside a dataframe, you'll see it cuted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([n])
print(df)
#          0
#0  0.074236
```

Nevertheless, you can get its real lenght anyway (similarly as you can see in [the guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#applying-elementwise-functions)):

```
df.applymap(lambda n:len(str(n)))
#    0
#0  19
```

In **my case** it was 19.

Answer (score 0):

So here it shows 18:

```
In [197]: df4
Out[197]: 
        one       two     three
a  1.394981  1.772517       NaN
b  0.343054  1.912123 -0.050390
c  0.695246  1.478369  1.227435
d       NaN  0.279344 -0.613172

In [198]: def f(x):
   .....:     return len(str(x))
   .....: 

In [199]: df4["one"].map(f)
Out[199]: 
a    18 <- here
b    19
c    18
d     3
Name: one, dtype: int64
```

That's because `1.394981` is a prettified representation of a floating-point number. This is done to help a human read and understand the number. However, the computer deals with numbers with much more precision. Basically, the exact number here is *not*, `1.394981`, but is rather a more precise value, so it *actually* has 18 digits.

---

In fact, you can see that this number first appears here:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ....:     {
   ....:         "one": pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=["a", "b", "c"]),
   ....:         "two": pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=["a", "b", "c", "d"]),
   ....:         "three": pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=["b", "c", "d"]),
   ....:     }
   ....: )
   ....: 

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
        one       two     three
a  1.394981  1.772517       NaN
b  0.343054  1.912123 -0.050390
c  0.695246  1.478369  1.227435
d       NaN  0.279344 -0.613172
```

So, these are random numbers generated by `np.random.randn(3)`. You *could* get *exactly* `1.394981`, but it's quite unlikely - they actually got some long floating-point number that has 18 digits.

Comment: a little clarification, the number actually has 17 digits and a point

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I just tried to rerun the code with slight modification as below:

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. I have just tried this an it works. It's all down to the precision. Many Thanks for your help. The issue can be closed now!